# Queries, GO statements and transactions in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

How does SQL interpret a query structured like this -

```
[create some table and insert some data]
GO
[create another table and insert some data]
GO
```

My understanding is that it executes the statements sequentially, but does it also commit the changes one by one (i.e., once it reaches the end of the first batch, it inserts into the table it created at the start of the  batch), or does it wait until the entire query successfully executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GO statements are used to separate batches of commands.  If you do not specifically initiate a transaction, SQL will do it for you.

In the case you have described, a autocommit transaction will be wrapped around each of your "create some table" commands, and your "insert some data" commands.

Each statement is executed sequentially. You will end up with two separate batches of two commands each, wrapped with their own auto-committed transaction.  4 transactions total.

Comment: Hmm, so, should I be worried if I already see that the second table was created (actually, these are SELECT INTO statements), but yet no data exists in the first table? There's really no reason for this to happen, the only change I've made to this query since it ran successfully, was to add a left join, and no changes were performed to the underlying data. So that seems to indicate that,at the very least, it doesn't commit those transactions sequentially...

Comment: +1 but it might be clearer to avoid use of the word "implicit" as `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON` means something different. It is an auto committed transaction.

Answer (score 1):

`GO` is a statement used by several MS tools, it is **NOT** SQL.

It is used by these tools to signify the end of a batch of statements.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx): (thanks @datagod)

> GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor.

Comment: @Alexander = It is _not_ t-sql either. It is a keyword that SSMS, SQLCMD and other _tools_ understand, not SQL SERVER itself.

Comment: A pointless factoid irrelevant to the question at hand. And yes, I have read MSDN on this point, before you were so kind as to provide it.